Independent claim rejection consequences on its dependent claims
If an independent claim is too generic and therefore it gets rejected and we agree to remove it, which of the followings will happen?
a. It will get rejected together with all of its dependent claims; or,
b. They allow us to make changes/edits like making the current dependent claims to become independent in the revision that the original independent claim is removed.


It will get rejected together with all of its dependent claims

Because a dependent claim adds details, is not necessarily properly rejected solely on the prior art that was used to reject the parent claim. However, many examiners automatically reject all of the dependent claims with weak justifications whenever they feel they are able to reject an independent claim. To some extent this practice is justifiable because if they are correct about the rejection of the independent claim you can't get away without amending anyways.

They allow us to make changes/edits like making the current dependent claims to become independent in the revision that the original independent claim is removed.

In the U.S., one is generally allowed to revise claims during prosection, sometimes subject to additional fees if an RCE is necessary. Note that the revised claims can be properly rejected on written description grounds if they are not supported by the specification.
However, one is still subject to excess claim fees so depending on what the claim chain looks like it is not necessarily wise to convert all the immediately dependent claims into independent claims.
